# Alfresco Connectivity from C#

Tags: c#, alfresco

How can I connect with Alfresco from my C# Application through webservice? I have done the Login successfully but then I got stuck to access the rest of the methods. Its showing

> WSDoAllReceiver: Request does not contain required Security header.

Comment: @VoodooChild, it is an open source CMS

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that Alfresco supports CMIS, which is convenient for many usual repository operations. You can use Apache Chemistry, there's a port of this lib for .NET environment? (http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html)